# sane scanner not available via TWAIN/Wine

Tags: fedora, wine, scanner

I have a scanner (Fujitsu ix500) connected via USB with a Fedora 29 machine. I can use the scanner just fine using GNOME's [simple-scan](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/simple-scan).

Also it seems the scanner is well supported via sane:

```
$ scanimage -L
device `fujitsu:ScanSnap iX500:1244428' is a FUJITSU ScanSnap iX500 scanner
```

Now I want to run some (proprietary) Windows application which came bundled with the scanner. The application seems to work just fine using Wine Staging 4.0-rc4 (Fedora default). I have the "wine-twain" package installed.

However the Windows application only lists a "gphoto camera" but not the scanner. Is there anything special to make sane scanners available for Wine applications?

Answer (score 0):

Well, sometimes its way too simple: Of course my Linux uses x86_64 and of course this Windows application is 32-bit only. Now I did install "wine.686" but not a 32 bit "sane-backends-drivers-scanners" package.

Once I installed that package the scanner showed up in the wine application :-)
(I doesn't scan correctly but that is likely another issue).